# Printing parallel arrays that contain different types of data to a file

Tags: arrays, c

so I'm trying to print data from 4 different arrays in this form:

```
Alex 599659008.00 19701112 2010
Mark 599232832.00 19702315 2015
Ali 59965680.00 197012415 2020
```

as you can see there are 4 arrays 2 contain integers, 1 float and 1 contain names (which's a multidimensional array) so how can I print them to a file like that form.
the arrays are defined like this:

```
char names[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
int stdID[MAXSIZE];
float phones[MAXSIZE];
int registrationYear[MAXSIZE];
```

Comment: `float phones`??

Comment: @WeatherVane that's what I'm asked to do yup, float phones I also don't understand why the project asks me to do that xD

Comment: Anyway, `fprintf(myfile, "%s %.2f %d %d\n", names[i], phones[i], stdID[i], registrationYear[i]);`

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you so much you solved the problem.

Comment: If you have numbers with 11 significant digits they should be in `double` not `float`. But  a phone number should be a string, not a numeric variable of any type.

Comment: Have you learnt about `struct`s yet? It seems to me like you should create a `struct` with `name`, `stdID`, `phone` and `registrationYear` and then _one_ array of such `struct`s.instead.

Comment: Azibc, `char names[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];` is very strange.  I'd expect something more like `char names[MAXSIZE][NAME_SIZE];`

Answer (score 1):

You need structure to agregate the data, not separate arrays.

```
#define MAXNAME 64

typedef struct
{
    int stdID;
    float phone;
    int registrationYear;
    char name[MAXNAME];
}person_t;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    person_t people[];
}database_t;

void print_database(FILE *fo, const database_t *db)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; index < db -> size; index++)
    {
        fprintf(fo, "%s %.2f %d %d\n", db -> people[index].name, db -> people[index].phone, 
                db -> people[index].stdID, db -> people[index].registrationYear);
    }
}

database_t db = {.size = 3, .people = {
    {.name = "Alex",  .phone = 599659008.00,  .stdID = 19701112, .registrationYear = 2010},
    {.name = "Mark",  .phone = 599232832.00,  .stdID = 19701112, .registrationYear = 2010},
    {.name = "Ali",   .phone = 599659008.00,  .stdID = 19701112, .registrationYear = 2010},
    }};


int main(void)
{
    print_database(stdout, &db);
}
```

Comment: it's a great idea, however, I'm not allowed to make a structure.